# how to create a VB script file without a pop up window

Tags: vbscript

I googled a code that works just as I wanted,
But when I schedule it in task manager issue occurs ..after every pop up screen i need to click ok..then only the file gets updated.Please let me know what changes are to be done so that after running VBS it silently updates the file.

actual code:
source:http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/scripts/vbscript_disk_space_usage_report.aspx

```
OPTION EXPLICIT

CONST strComputer = "."
CONST strReport = "D:\diskspace.txt"

DIM objWMIService, objItem, colItems
DIM strDriveType, strDiskSize, txt

SET objWMIService = GETOBJECT("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
SET colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=3")
txt = "Drive" & vbtab & "Size" & vbtab & "Used" & vbtab & "Free" & vbtab & "Free(%)" & vbcrlf
FOR EACH objItem in colItems

    DIM pctFreeSpace,strFreeSpace,strusedSpace

    pctFreeSpace = INT((objItem.FreeSpace / objItem.Size) * 1000)/10
    strDiskSize = Int(objItem.Size /1073741824) & "Gb"
    strFreeSpace = Int(objItem.FreeSpace /1073741824) & "Gb"
    strUsedSpace = Int((objItem.Size-objItem.FreeSpace)/1073741824) & "Gb"
    txt = txt & objItem.Name & vbtab & strDiskSize & vbtab & strUsedSpace & vbTab & strFreeSpace & vbtab & pctFreeSpace & vbcrlf

NEXT

writeTextFile txt, strReport
wscript.echo "Report written to " & strReport & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & txt

' Procedure to write output to a text file
PRIVATE SUB writeTextFile(BYVAL txt,BYVAL strTextFilePath)
  DIM objFSO,objTextFile
  SET objFSO = CREATEOBJECT("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  SET objTextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strTextFilePath)
  objTextFile.Write(txt)
  objTextFile.Close
  SET objTextFile = NOTHING
END SUB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popup massage genarated by `wscript.echo` if you delete that line, code will run silently

```
wscript.echo "Report written to " & strReport & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Call the script with `cscript script_file.vbs` instead of `wscript script_file.vbs`.